# Find $\int\frac{1}{2\sin (x)+3\cos (x)+1}$ $\Tiny{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**Question**

> Evaluate the following integral:  $\int\frac{1}{2\sin (x)+3\cos (x)+1} \small{dx}$

Now, I've tried a couple of different substitutions and integrating partially but unfortunately, to no luck, I was wondering about your thoughts on it. I'd also be very thankful if someone were to have a complete answer

Thanks in advance. :)

**Attempt**

$$\int\frac{dx}{2\sin x+3\cos x+1}= \int\frac{dx}{2\left(\frac{2\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}\right)+3\left(\frac{1-\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}\right)+1} \\= \int\frac{dx}{\frac{4\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}+\frac{3-3\tan\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}+1}$$

All in all I end up with $$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dt}{(t+\frac{1}{2})^2-(\frac{\sqrt3}{2})^2}$$ which is incorrect.

Comment: Your question is more likely to be well-received if you include your attempts at a "couple of different substitutions and integrating partially".

Comment: I've attached a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for including some of your work! Unfortunately it's somewhat illegible (although your strategy of rewriting in terms of $\tan\left(\frac x2\right)$ is a good [first step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)); transcribing it to [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would help significantly.

Comment: Thanks, I have trascribed it to MathJax

Comment: Well done! I've cleaned up some parts and have rescinded my close vote. In the meantime, you can continue to simplify the integral by collecting all the terms into one fraction, and you're ready to carry out the aforementioned substitution.

Comment: I've edited my message once again, I end up with a wrong answer. Could you please help me solve it =)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193829/simpler-alternative-for-int-fracdx2-sin-x3-cos-x7 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154939/calculating-int-fracdx13-sin-x-cos-x and probably others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=2\arctan(1+s)$, i.e. $s=\tan(x/2)-1$,  and $dx=\frac{2dt}{1+(1+s)^2}$. Then your integral becomes
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{2\sin x+3\cos x +1}&=
\int \frac{ds}{3-s^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\left[\int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{3}+s}+\int \frac{ds}{\sqrt{3}-s}\right]
\\ &
\\ &
=\frac{\ln(\sqrt{3}+s)-\ln(\sqrt{3}-s)}{2\sqrt{3}}
\\ &
\\ &
=\frac1{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{3}+s}{\sqrt{3}-s}
=\frac1{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{3}+\tan(x/2)-1}{\sqrt{3}-\tan(x/2)+1},
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the half-angle substitution is  $t=x+a$, with $\sin a =\frac3{\sqrt{13}}$ and $\cos a =\frac2{\sqrt{13}}$

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{2\sin x+3\cos x+1}dx\\
=& \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{13}\sin t +1}
= \int \frac{d(\frac{\sqrt{13}+\sin t}{\cos t})}{(\frac{\sqrt{13}+\sin t}{\cos t})^2-12}
=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{12}}\coth^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{13}+\sin t}{\sqrt{12}\cos t}\\
= & \ \frac1{\sqrt{12}}\coth^{-1}\frac{{13}+2\sin x+3\cos x}{\sqrt{12}\ (3\sin x-2\cos x )}+C\\
\end{align}